# Create standalone app with additional files with PyInstaller (OS X)

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I want to create a standalone executable file for a python code that uses two txt files which define some parameters.

If somebody changes the parameters of those text files, the standalone application should take it into account. The text files do not have to be fixed in the final code.

I am using PyInstaller under OS X. I create the executable file, but it does not read the text files. The python code reads the files without a problem.

Those are the commands I use to create the executable file:

```
python utils/makespec.py --onefile ../extest/exec_test.py
nueye$ python utils/build.py exec_test/exec_test.spec
```

What I am doing wrong? What should I add to my procedure?

Comment: How are you referencing the two text files in your Python program in respect to their paths on your file system?

Comment: @Mat, I just use their name in the function `config.read(configfilename)` of the ConfigParser library.
I am not referencing it in the `setup.py` file.
What is the appropriate way of doing it?

Comment: @Mat, I have discovered the actual problem of why the executable is not reading the text files. The output of `os.getcwd()` is not the same path where the executable file is. I will look forward how to set the path to be the same as the location of the file.
Thank you for your response.